# SharePoint Online Rest, multilookup

Tags: javascript, rest, csom, cross-domain

I'm trying to fetch some data from the hostweb from my SharePoint hosted app. This is all going well, however I am having a problem when I try to fetch a multi lookup fields value. Below is my request:

```
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Aktiviteter')/items?&select=Title,Location/Id&expand=Location&@target='" + hostweburl + "'"
```

above request is working, and is fetching the list items, however not the lookup field. The lookup field is a multi lookup field to another custom list on the hostweb. Is there a way to expand when fetching multi lookups, or am I fooling myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Multiple-Column Lookup value* is represented as an array of [`SP.FieldLookupValue objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246742%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

**How to read *multi-valued* lookup field using SharePoint 2013 REST**

Assume `Employee` list with a multi-valued lookup field `Departments`

Then the query: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items` returns an array of lookup ids, for example:

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'','Employees',
  function(items){
     if(items.length > 0)
        console.log(items[0].DepartmentsId);   //returns an array [LookupId1, LookupId1 .. LookupIdN]
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(error.responseText);     
  });
```

The query:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employees')/items?$select=Departments/Title,Departments/Id&$expand=Departments
```

returns projected Departments array of objects as shown below:

```
getListItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'?$select=Departments/Title,Departments/Id&$expand=Departments','Employees',
  function(items){
     if(items.length > 0)
        if(items[0].Departments.results.length > 0) {
           console.log(items[0].Departments.results[0].Title);   
           console.log(items[0].Departments.results[0].Id);   
        }   
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(error.responseText);     
  });
```

---

SharePoint 2013 REST read list items function:

```
function getListItems(url, query, listName, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking your uri, it's look fine, I believe that your problem is how parse de data. I set an uri and this return this to me:

```
<entry m:etag="&quot;9&quot;">
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Familias_Controles" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Familias_Controles" href="Web/Lists(guid'028c99e1-d98c-4206-a248-1ac4e3c64381')/Items(296)/Familias_Controles">
    <m:inline>
        <feed>
            <id>1cd20d60-cb23-4578-9582-a0159aaa165e</id>
            <title />
            <updated>2015-09-09T12:40:40Z</updated>
            <entry>
                <id>32cda293-4079-432e-8481-9f32d62e8bce</id>
                <category term="SP.Data.LM_x005f_Familia_x005f_ControlListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                <title />
                <updated>2015-09-09T12:40:40Z</updated>
                <author>
                <name />
                </author>
                <content type="application/xml">
                <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:Id>
                </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <id>ffcc5b9f-e08f-44ad-a9c7-6bd27fa1acfc</id>
                <category term="SP.Data.LM_x005f_Familia_x005f_ControlListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                <title />
                <updated>2015-09-09T12:40:40Z</updated>
                <author>
                <name />
                </author>
                <content type="application/xml">
                <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">4</d:Id>
                </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
        </feed>
    </m:inline>
</link>
```

And JavaScript parse this data like this:

```
{
"d":
    {"results":[
        {
        "__metadata":{"id":"d6662447-1630-4e77-9ec8-20b601a7f091","uri":"http://molymetsig.colabra.cl/sites/sig/molynor/_api/Web/Lists(guid'028c99e1-d98c-4206-a248-1ac4e3c64381')/Items(296)","etag":"\"9\"","type":"SP.Data.Gestor_x005f_DocumentalItem"},
        "Familias_Controles":
            {"results":[
                    {
                        "__metadata":
                        {
                            "id":"f80ddc7f-f5c4-47df-be85-3e86292f431d",
                            "type":"SP.Data.LM_x005f_Familia_x005f_ControlListItem"
                        }
                        ,
                        "Id":2
                    },
                    {   
                        "__metadata":
                        {
                            "id":"b3c5e814-7e6a-47c0-993d-5dbe17deaf91",
                            "type":"SP.Data.LM_x005f_Familia_x005f_ControlListItem"
                        },
                        "Id":4
                    }
                ]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

You could get the data like this

```
data data.d.results[0].Location.results
```

Wich one is an array of id's.
I hope I was not too complicated.

Greetings :)

Comment: I will give that a go a bit later and get back to you :)